# Recursion: How can I remove

Tags: javascript, loops

here's my code:

```
var asset = ['1234_12', '1234_34', '1234_33', '4321_22', '4321_90'];

var largest = removeElements(asset);

function removeElements(asset) {
    var retVal = [];
    for (i = 0; i < asset.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < asset.length; j++) {
            if (asset[i].split('_')[0] == asset[j].split('_')[0]) {
                if (asset[i].split('_')[1].split('.')[0] > asset[j].split('_')[1].split('.')[0]) {
                    retVal = removeElements(asset, asset[j]);
                    for (var k = 0; k < retVal.length; k++) {
                        for (var l = 0; l < retVal.length; l++) {
                            if (retVal[k].split('_')[0] == retVal[l].split('_')[0]) {
                                removeElements(retVal);
                            } else {
                                return retVal;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Here's the structure of array:

```
var asset = ['1234_12', '1234_34', '1234_33', '4321_22', '4321_90'];
```

What I want is to get largest in `'1234'` or `'4321'` series. For example, in this case, I need to grab `'1234_34'` and `'4321_90'`.

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this for real ?

Comment: Yes. Updated the code.

Comment: For each "number category" (1234), I'd use a map to convert all array items to the "last" number and then filter it to the highest of those numbers. Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making it harder than it is for yourself. You can just iterate over each item and store the matched values in an object:

```
var asset = ['1234_12', '1234_34', '1234_33', '4321_22', '4321_90'];
var intermediate = {};
asset.forEach(function(v) {
  var parts = v.split('_');
  var key = parts[0];
  var val = parts[1];
  if (!intermediate[key] || intermediate[key] < val) {
    intermediate[key] = val;
  }
});
```

This will produce an object like:

```
{"1234": "34", "4321": "90"}
```

Which you can then be turned into the expected array:

```
var output = Object.keys(intermediate).map(function(key) {
  return key + '_' + intermediate[key];
});
console.log(output); // ["1234_34", "4321_90"]
```

Take a look at [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you @andlrc and others for help and suggestions.

Comment: @SeattleAls Now it's time to read it twice and rewrite it yourself :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of something that will grab those values (see the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fakahumene/edit?js,console)):

```
var asset = ['1234_12', '1234_34', '1234_33', '4321_22', '4321_90'];

var ids = _.values(_.mapValues(asset.reduce(function(agg, curr) {
  var parts = curr.split('_');

  agg[parts[0]] = agg[parts[0]] || [];

  agg[parts[0]].push(parts[1]);

  return agg;
}, {}), function(value, key) {
  return [key, Math.max.apply(Math, value)].join('_');
}));

console.log(ids); // => ["1234_34", "4321_90"]
```

It uses [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) for convenience, but the principles are the same without it.

First you split each string into a key-value pair of the prefix and suffix (so `1234_12` and `1234_34`, etc., becomes like `{ 1234: ['12', '34'] }`). Then you just find the max value in that array and join it back with its key.

Comment: I guess you can change `_.values(_.mapValues(asset.reduce(...), ...), ...)` to something like `_(asset).reduce(...).mapValues(...).values(...).value()`

Comment: @andlrc yeah good call with the chaining (definitely more readable)